# Tomcat Web Application Manager - is it possible to limit what each user role can see?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, access-control

I couldn't find anything regarding this on the Internet, so hopefully an expert here could help answer my question.

I have set up the Tomcat Web Application Manager on my test server, created some roles/users in `tomcat-users.xml` as follows:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
<user username="user1" password="password" roles="manager"/>
```

`admin` is supposed to have full rights on the WebApp Manager, while `user1` (and perhaps subsequent users) is for users who have been granted permission to upload/deploy their WAR files.

Right now they have the same roles, so obviously they see the same UI upon logging in, but I want `user1` to see only the deploy/upload option - essentially limited access to the WebApp Manager.

Is it possible to achieve something like this? If yes, how? If no, what would be an acceptable compromise?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't look very hard if you couldn't find this. It's under the "Manager" section of the Tomcat Users' Guide:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

With the standard user-acces roles, you cannot do what you are trying to do. Fortunately, there's nothing stopping you from inventing some.

Let's say you want to set up different roles for `deploy` and `undeploy`. Just add them to `tomcat-users.xml` like this:

```
<role rolename="deploy"/>
<role rolename="undeploy"/>
```

Now, modify the `manager` webapp's web.xml and add some `auth-constraints` that will allow these new roles to access certain specific functions:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Manual Deployment</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/deploy</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
     <role-name>deploy</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Manual Deployment</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/undeploy</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
    <role-name>undeploy</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Note that you will also have to modify the existing `<web-resource-collection>` for `/html/*` so that users with any appropriate role (for instance, those with only the 'deploy' role) can access the GUI itself in order to get to those functions configured above.